# I want to switch between nav tabs from typescript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have two tabs,
1) Annotation and 
2) Data String.
in a nav tabs

```html
    <nav>
       <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill " id="nav-tab2 " role="tablist ">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-annotations-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-annotations" role="tab">Annotations</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-datastringbox-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-datastringbox" role="tab">String</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

And the respective divs are as follow:

```html
    <div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent2">
         <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-annotations">
              <app-pvgfp-annotation-list></app-pvgfp-annotation-list>
         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-datastringbox">
              <div class="line-loader " [hidden]="!lineLoader"></div>
                   <textarea rows="5 " class="form-control"> 
                   </textarea>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

And annotation List component consists of 
some a-tags, all of which consists of some links.
which(app-pvgfp-annotation-list component) are as follows:

```html
    <div>
        <a href="htts://www.google.com">Google</a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
    </div>
```

Now I want, On click of that link, I have to open the #nav-datastringbox tab.

So, Basically, My question is how to open another tab from typescript.

Can anybody please help me to solve this.

Comment: Can you please provide any example code using **stackblitz** ?

Comment: You can't open a tab from Typescript because your page doesn't use Typescript at all. It all gets compiled into JavaScript at runtime. In short, no browser currently understands Typescript. The good news, however, is that you can open a tab from JavaScript. Could you please explain what you mean by *"On click of that link"* exactly? Which link?

Comment: @tao

there is function called test(), from there, I want to switch to the other tab